# SAS - proc freq...insufficient memory?

Tags: memory, sas

I've rarely used proc freq before. I'm trying to run the following and I receive an error says SAS is unable to allocate sufficient memory. The dataset has about 15,000 records. What are my alternatives here?

```
proc freq data=dsb_un noprint; 
table bsn*dsb / out=dsb_un2(where=(count>1) drop=percent); 
run;
```

Comment: How many unique values of BSN and DSB do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dropping percent, the following should be identical:

```
proc freq data=dsb_un noprint;
by bsn;
tables dsb/out=dsb_un2(where=(count>1) drop=percent);
run;
```

The BY statement should decrease the memory allocation significantly.  You also could use PROC SQL in a similar way that would probably fit fine in memory.

The problem is likely that DSB and BSN are mostly unique values each, so you probably have something like 10k+ values for each - making a master table of 10k*10k or 1e8 cells, requiring 8e8 bytes of memory, which may be beyond your available memory for SAS.

Comment: Before seeing your suggestion I was actually able to get my original proc freq to work by adding a data step before it to narrow down the records to just a few hundred. I just tested out your suggestion as well and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this before as well.  The way I got around it was simply not to use `proc freq`.  I believe I used `proc summary` instead.  It can count frequencies just as well.

First a test dataset:

```
data tmp;
  set sashelp.class;
  dummy = 1;
run;
```

Using your original `freq` approach:

```
proc freq data=tmp noprint; 
  table sex*age / out=freq1(where=(count>1) drop=percent); 
run;
```

Using a `proc summary` approach:

```
proc summary data=tmp noprint nway missing;
  class sex age;
  var dummy;
  output out=freq2(where=(dummy>1) drop=_type_ _freq_) sum=;
run;
```

Note that `proc summary` may need a dummy variable that you can calculate against.  Hence the creation of the `dummy=1` flag in my test dataset.